# Update and Delete error in Spring-boot and mongo db CRUD application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, api, rest

I am trying to create a CRUD application using Spring-boot and Mongo DB.
I am getting error the in the update and delete operations

During Delete, there is a timestamp error showing and on update a new object is getting created instead of updating the existing object. I have attached the controller and service layer codes.
Can anyone please find a solution for this.

Controller Layer

```
package com.springrest.springrest.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springrest.springrest.entities.Course;
import com.springrest.springrest.services.CourseService;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private CourseService courseService;
    
    @GetMapping("/courses")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCourses(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.courseService.GetCourses());
    }       
    
    
    @PostMapping("/courses")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addCourse(@RequestBody Course course)
    {
        Course save=this.courseService.addCourse(course);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(save);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCourse(@PathVariable String courseId ){
        Optional<Course> save=this.courseService.getCourse(Integer.parseInt(courseId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(save); 
    }
    
    
    
    @PutMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCourse(@PathVariable String courseId,
    @RequestBody Course course)
    {
        Optional<Course> save=Optional.ofNullable(this.courseService.updateCourse(Integer.parseInt
                (courseId),course));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(save);
    }   
    
    @DeleteMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
    public void deleteCourse(@PathVariable String courseId)
    {
        this.courseService.deleteCourse(Integer.parseInt(courseId));
        //return ResponseEntity.ok(this.courseService.deleteCourse(Integer.parseInt(courseId)));
    }
}
```

Service Layer

```
package com.springrest.springrest.services;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.springrest.springrest.entities.Course;
import com.springrest.springrest.repository.CourseRepository;


@Service
public class CourseServiceimpl implements CourseService 
{
    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository userlist;
    
    public List<Course> GetCourses() {
        return this.userlist.findAll();
    }
    
    public Course addCourse(Course course) {
        return this.userlist.save(course);
    }
    
    public Optional<Course> getCourse(int courseId)
    {
        Optional<Course> c=this.userlist.findById(courseId);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public Course updateCourse(int courseId, Course course) 
    {
        Course c=this.userlist.findById(courseId).get();
        c.setId(course.getId());
        c.setTitle(course.getTitle());
        c.setDescription(course.getDescription());
        return this.userlist.save(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCourse(int courseId) 
    {
        //Course c= this.userlist.findById(courseId).get();
        this.userlist.deleteById(courseId);     
    }

    
}
```

Entity Layer

```
package com.springrest.springrest.entities;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

@Document(collection="Course")
public class Course {

    @Field( name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Field(name="title")
    private String title;
    
    @Field(name="description")
    private String description;
    
    public Course(int id, String title, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Course() {
        super();
        
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
}
```

This is the error I am getting on a Delete Request
{
"timestamp": "2022-11-09T18:45:58.630+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"path": "/api/courses/147"
}

Comment: The wrapper `500` isn't helpful for debugging purposes.  What is the actual error that the server is generating (perhaps captured in the application logs)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error in get and save operations? Because although you inject CourseService in controller, you did not override get and save operations methods in CourseServiceimpl class.

Comment: The updateCourse and delete methods are not working as expected.